# How to create grouped boxplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

Is there a way to group boxplots in matplotlib?

Assume we have three groups "A", "B", and "C" and for each we want to create a boxplot for both "apples" and "oranges". If a grouping is not possible directly, we can create all six combinations and place them linearly side by side. What would be to simplest way to visualize the groupings? I'm trying to avoid setting the tick labels to something like "A + apples" since my scenario involves much longer names than "A".

Answer (score 116, accepted):

How about using colors to differentiate between "apples" and "oranges" and spacing to separate "A", "B" and "C"?

Something like this:

```
from pylab import plot, show, savefig, xlim, figure, \
                hold, ylim, legend, boxplot, setp, axes

# function for setting the colors of the box plots pairs
def setBoxColors(bp):
    setp(bp['boxes'][0], color='blue')
    setp(bp['caps'][0], color='blue')
    setp(bp['caps'][1], color='blue')
    setp(bp['whiskers'][0], color='blue')
    setp(bp['whiskers'][1], color='blue')
    setp(bp['fliers'][0], color='blue')
    setp(bp['fliers'][1], color='blue')
    setp(bp['medians'][0], color='blue')

    setp(bp['boxes'][1], color='red')
    setp(bp['caps'][2], color='red')
    setp(bp['caps'][3], color='red')
    setp(bp['whiskers'][2], color='red')
    setp(bp['whiskers'][3], color='red')
    setp(bp['fliers'][2], color='red')
    setp(bp['fliers'][3], color='red')
    setp(bp['medians'][1], color='red')

# Some fake data to plot
A= [[1, 2, 5,],  [7, 2]]
B = [[5, 7, 2, 2, 5], [7, 2, 5]]
C = [[3,2,5,7], [6, 7, 3]]

fig = figure()
ax = axes()
hold(True)

# first boxplot pair
bp = boxplot(A, positions = [1, 2], widths = 0.6)
setBoxColors(bp)

# second boxplot pair
bp = boxplot(B, positions = [4, 5], widths = 0.6)
setBoxColors(bp)

# thrid boxplot pair
bp = boxplot(C, positions = [7, 8], widths = 0.6)
setBoxColors(bp)

# set axes limits and labels
xlim(0,9)
ylim(0,9)
ax.set_xticklabels(['A', 'B', 'C'])
ax.set_xticks([1.5, 4.5, 7.5])

# draw temporary red and blue lines and use them to create a legend
hB, = plot([1,1],'b-')
hR, = plot([1,1],'r-')
legend((hB, hR),('Apples', 'Oranges'))
hB.set_visible(False)
hR.set_visible(False)

savefig('boxcompare.png')
show()
```

[image: grouped box plot]

Comment: That is a very nice solution since you have both groping by colors and grouping by positions! Since it looks like there is no built in functionality this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: This example works perfectly with matplotlib 1.3.1 but not 1.4.0 because of https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3544 (although the data you chose has no outliers so that the problem would not show, you will still get an error when accessing `bp['fliers'][2]`).

Comment: In pandas it's apparently possible to set the color of the boxplots just by giving a color property: `data.plot(kind='box',color='blue')`

Comment: With regards to the fliers, it should now be:
`plt.setp(bp['fliers'][0], markeredgecolor='blue')` and `plt.setp(bp['fliers'][1], markeredgecolor='red')`

Comment: Is that possible that the trick to have the legend is not working anymore with the new matplotlib update? set_visible(False) apparently makes the line disappear even in the legend.

Comment: Can this be done in matplotlib as opposed to pylab? read somewhere pylab is discouraged now

Comment: Insted of drawing temporary lines, you can create custom lines like explained in matplotlib documentation: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/custom_legends.html

Comment: Another way to set the color fill of your boxplots: take the "# fill with colors" part from here [link](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/gallery/statistics/boxplot_color.html) and insert `patch_artist=True` into your `bp=boxplot()`

Answer (score 88):

Here is my version. It stores data based on categories.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data_a = [[1,2,5], [5,7,2,2,5], [7,2,5]]
data_b = [[6,4,2], [1,2,5,3,2], [2,3,5,1]]

ticks = ['A', 'B', 'C']

def set_box_color(bp, color):
    plt.setp(bp['boxes'], color=color)
    plt.setp(bp['whiskers'], color=color)
    plt.setp(bp['caps'], color=color)
    plt.setp(bp['medians'], color=color)

plt.figure()

bpl = plt.boxplot(data_a, positions=np.array(xrange(len(data_a)))*2.0-0.4, sym='', widths=0.6)
bpr = plt.boxplot(data_b, positions=np.array(xrange(len(data_b)))*2.0+0.4, sym='', widths=0.6)
set_box_color(bpl, '#D7191C') # colors are from http://colorbrewer2.org/
set_box_color(bpr, '#2C7BB6')

# draw temporary red and blue lines and use them to create a legend
plt.plot([], c='#D7191C', label='Apples')
plt.plot([], c='#2C7BB6', label='Oranges')
plt.legend()

plt.xticks(xrange(0, len(ticks) * 2, 2), ticks)
plt.xlim(-2, len(ticks)*2)
plt.ylim(0, 8)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('boxcompare.png')
```

I am short of reputation so I cannot post an image to here.
You can run it and see the result. Basically it's very similar to what Molly did.

Note that, depending on the version of python you are using, you may need to replace `xrange` with `range`

[image: Result of this code]

Comment: It seems like you do not use your variables 'mu' and 'alpha'. Otherwise I really like your solution since it is close to a universal solution, only the number of categories that the plot is grouped by needs adjustment of the code.

Comment: This is the best solution among all answers on this page imo. As @Horstinator pointed out, it doesn't require the same number of samples in apple vs orange.

Comment: This is a top answer! Only thing would be to make it flexible for more than 2 groups

Comment: for future visitors: 'xrange()' becomes 'range()' in Python 3

Comment: cleanest solution, upvoted!

Answer (score 42):

A simple way would be to use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/).
I adapted an example from the [plotting documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#box-plotting):

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd, numpy as np

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(12,2), columns=['Apples', 'Oranges'] )

In [3]: df['Categories'] = pd.Series(list('AAAABBBBCCCC'))

In [4]: pd.options.display.mpl_style = 'default'

In [5]: df.boxplot(by='Categories')
Out[5]: 
array([<matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot object at 0x51a5190>,
       <matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot object at 0x53fddd0>], dtype=object)
```

[image: pandas boxplot]

Comment: I can't figure out how to do the inverse of this - boxplots for each fruit, grouped by categories (same grouping as molly's annwer). Is there a way?

Comment: Not sure what "the inverse" should be. If you mean exactly the kind of plot from molly's answer (only one subplot), this is not possible with a pandas plotting command. You have to use matplotlib and a more complicated script.

Answer (score 27):

Mock data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Group':['A','A','A','B','C','B','B','C','A','C'],\
                  'Apple':np.random.rand(10),'Orange':np.random.rand(10)})
df = df[['Group','Apple','Orange']]

        Group    Apple     Orange
    0      A  0.465636  0.537723
    1      A  0.560537  0.727238
    2      A  0.268154  0.648927
    3      B  0.722644  0.115550
    4      C  0.586346  0.042896
    5      B  0.562881  0.369686
    6      B  0.395236  0.672477
    7      C  0.577949  0.358801
    8      A  0.764069  0.642724
    9      C  0.731076  0.302369
```

You can use the Seaborn library for these plots. First `melt` the dataframe to format data and then create the boxplot of your choice.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
dd=pd.melt(df,id_vars=['Group'],value_vars=['Apple','Orange'],var_name='fruits')
sns.boxplot(x='Group',y='value',data=dd,hue='fruits')
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

The accepted answer uses pylab and works for 2 groups. What if we have more?

Here is the flexible generic solution with matplotlib [image: matplotlib output showing 3 groups of 4 boxplots within each group each series has a different color]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

# there are 4 individuals, each one tested under 3 different settings

# --- Random data, e.g. results per algorithm:

# Invidual 1
d1_1 = [1,1,2,2,3,3]
d1_2 = [3,3,4,4,5,5]
d1_3 = [5,5,6,6,7,7]

# Individual 2
d2_1 = [7,7,8,8,9,9]
d2_2 = [9,9,10,10,11,11]
d2_3 = [11,11,12,12,13,13]

# Individual 3
d3_1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
d3_2 = [4,5,6,7,8,9]
d3_3 = [10,11,12,13,14,15]

# Individual 4
d4_1 = [1,1,2,2,3,3]
d4_2 = [9,9,10,10,11,11]
d4_3 = [10,11,12,13,14,15]


# --- Combining your data:
data_group1 = [d1_1, d1_2, d1_3]
data_group2 = [d2_1, d2_2, d2_3]
data_group3 = [d3_1, d3_2, d3_3]
data_group4 = [d4_1, d4_2, d4_3]

colors = ['pink', 'lightblue', 'lightgreen', 'violet']

# we compare the performances of the 4 individuals within the same set of 3 settings 
data_groups = [data_group1, data_group2, data_group3, data_group4]

# --- Labels for your data:
labels_list = ['a','b', 'c']
width       = 1/len(labels_list)
xlocations  = [ x*((1+ len(data_groups))*width) for x in range(len(data_group1)) ]

symbol      = 'r+'
ymin        = min ( [ val  for dg in data_groups  for data in dg for val in data ] )
ymax        = max ( [ val  for dg in data_groups  for data in dg for val in data ])

ax = pl.gca()
ax.set_ylim(ymin,ymax)

ax.grid(True, linestyle='dotted')
ax.set_axisbelow(True)

pl.xlabel('X axis label')
pl.ylabel('Y axis label')
pl.title('title')

space = len(data_groups)/2
offset = len(data_groups)/2


# --- Offset the positions per group:

group_positions = []
for num, dg in enumerate(data_groups):    
    _off = (0 - space + (0.5+num))
    print(_off)
    group_positions.append([x+_off*(width+0.01) for x in xlocations])

for dg, pos, c in zip(data_groups, group_positions, colors):
    boxes = ax.boxplot(dg, 
                sym=symbol,
                labels=['']*len(labels_list),
    #            labels=labels_list,
                positions=pos, 
                widths=width, 
                boxprops=dict(facecolor=c),
    #             capprops=dict(color=c),
    #            whiskerprops=dict(color=c),
    #            flierprops=dict(color=c, markeredgecolor=c),                       
                medianprops=dict(color='grey'),
    #           notch=False,  
    #           vert=True, 
    #           whis=1.5,
    #           bootstrap=None, 
    #           usermedians=None, 
    #           conf_intervals=None,
                patch_artist=True,
                )
ax.set_xticks( xlocations )
ax.set_xticklabels( labels_list, rotation=0 )



pl.show()
```

Comment: The labels from `labels_list` don't actually show for me when I run this example, and when using only two data groups we have three notches (rather than two) under each x grouping, as if there were three boxes together. With four groups we have five notches. Also, as @baigyanik pointed out, the boxes in each group are reversed. Other than that, this is my favorite answer.

Comment: Thanks @Mutoh and baigyanik for noticing the issues. I've fixed the snipped and also added instructions to color differently the various boxplots

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to the conversation, I have found a more elegant way to change the color of the box plot by iterating over the dictionary of the object itself

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def color_box(bp, color):

    # Define the elements to color. You can also add medians, fliers and means
    elements = ['boxes','caps','whiskers']

    # Iterate over each of the elements changing the color
    for elem in elements:
        [plt.setp(bp[elem][idx], color=color) for idx in xrange(len(bp[elem]))]
    return

a = np.random.uniform(0,10,[100,5])    

bp = plt.boxplot(a)
color_box(bp, 'red')
```

[image: Original box plot]

[image: Modified box plot]

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function I wrote that takes Molly's code and some other code I've found on the internet to make slightly fancier grouped boxplots:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def custom_legend(colors, labels, linestyles=None):
    """ Creates a list of matplotlib Patch objects that can be passed to the legend(...) function to create a custom
        legend.

    :param colors: A list of colors, one for each entry in the legend. You can also include a linestyle, for example: 'k--'
    :param labels:  A list of labels, one for each entry in the legend.
    """

    if linestyles is not None:
        assert len(linestyles) == len(colors), "Length of linestyles must match length of colors."

    h = list()
    for k,(c,l) in enumerate(zip(colors, labels)):
        clr = c
        ls = 'solid'
        if linestyles is not None:
            ls = linestyles[k]
        patch = patches.Patch(color=clr, label=l, linestyle=ls)
        h.append(patch)
    return h


def grouped_boxplot(data, group_names=None, subgroup_names=None, ax=None, subgroup_colors=None,
                    box_width=0.6, box_spacing=1.0):
    """ Draws a grouped boxplot. The data should be organized in a hierarchy, where there are multiple
        subgroups for each main group.

    :param data: A dictionary of length equal to the number of the groups. The key should be the
                group name, the value should be a list of arrays. The length of the list should be
                equal to the number of subgroups.
    :param group_names: (Optional) The group names, should be the same as data.keys(), but can be ordered.
    :param subgroup_names: (Optional) Names of the subgroups.
    :param subgroup_colors: A list specifying the plot color for each subgroup.
    :param ax: (Optional) The axis to plot on.
    """

    if group_names is None:
        group_names = data.keys()

    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    plt.sca(ax)

    nsubgroups = np.array([len(v) for v in data.values()])
    assert len(np.unique(nsubgroups)) == 1, "Number of subgroups for each property differ!"
    nsubgroups = nsubgroups[0]

    if subgroup_colors is None:
        subgroup_colors = list()
        for k in range(nsubgroups):
            subgroup_colors.append(np.random.rand(3))
    else:
        assert len(subgroup_colors) == nsubgroups, "subgroup_colors length must match number of subgroups (%d)" % nsubgroups

    def _decorate_box(_bp, _d):
        plt.setp(_bp['boxes'], lw=0, color='k')
        plt.setp(_bp['whiskers'], lw=3.0, color='k')

        # fill in each box with a color
        assert len(_bp['boxes']) == nsubgroups
        for _k,_box in enumerate(_bp['boxes']):
            _boxX = list()
            _boxY = list()
            for _j in range(5):
                _boxX.append(_box.get_xdata()[_j])
                _boxY.append(_box.get_ydata()[_j])
            _boxCoords = zip(_boxX, _boxY)
            _boxPolygon = plt.Polygon(_boxCoords, facecolor=subgroup_colors[_k])
            ax.add_patch(_boxPolygon)

        # draw a black line for the median
        for _k,_med in enumerate(_bp['medians']):
            _medianX = list()
            _medianY = list()
            for _j in range(2):
                _medianX.append(_med.get_xdata()[_j])
                _medianY.append(_med.get_ydata()[_j])
                plt.plot(_medianX, _medianY, 'k', linewidth=3.0)

            # draw a black asterisk for the mean
            plt.plot([np.mean(_med.get_xdata())], [np.mean(_d[_k])], color='w', marker='*',
                      markeredgecolor='k', markersize=12)

    cpos = 1
    label_pos = list()
    for k in group_names:
        d = data[k]
        nsubgroups = len(d)
        pos = np.arange(nsubgroups) + cpos
        label_pos.append(pos.mean())
        bp = plt.boxplot(d, positions=pos, widths=box_width)
        _decorate_box(bp, d)
        cpos += nsubgroups + box_spacing

    plt.xlim(0, cpos-1)
    plt.xticks(label_pos, group_names)

    if subgroup_names is not None:
        leg = custom_legend(subgroup_colors, subgroup_names)
        plt.legend(handles=leg)
```

You can use the function(s) like this:

```
data = { 'A':[np.random.randn(100), np.random.randn(100) + 5],
         'B':[np.random.randn(100)+1, np.random.randn(100) + 9],
         'C':[np.random.randn(100)-3, np.random.randn(100) -5]
       }

grouped_boxplot(data, group_names=['A', 'B', 'C'], subgroup_names=['Apples', 'Oranges'], subgroup_colors=['#D02D2E', '#D67700'])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Grouped boxplots, towards subtle academic publication styling... ([source](https://petescully.co.uk/2016/06/30/boxplots-data-visualisation/))

***(Left)*** Python 2.7.12 Matplotlib v1.5.3. **(Right)** Python 3.7.3. Matplotlib v3.1.0.

[image: grouped boxplot example png for Python 2.7.12 Matplotlib v1.5.3] [image: grouped boxplot example png for Python 3.7.3 Matplotlib v3.1.0]

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# --- Your data, e.g. results per algorithm:
data1 = [5,5,4,3,3,5]
data2 = [6,6,4,6,8,5]
data3 = [7,8,4,5,8,2]
data4 = [6,9,3,6,8,4]

# --- Combining your data:
data_group1 = [data1, data2]
data_group2 = [data3, data4]

# --- Labels for your data:
labels_list = ['a','b']
xlocations  = range(len(data_group1))
width       = 0.3
symbol      = 'r+'
ymin        = 0
ymax        = 10

ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_ylim(ymin,ymax)
ax.set_xticklabels( labels_list, rotation=0 )
ax.grid(True, linestyle='dotted')
ax.set_axisbelow(True)
ax.set_xticks(xlocations)
plt.xlabel('X axis label')
plt.ylabel('Y axis label')
plt.title('title')

# --- Offset the positions per group:
positions_group1 = [x-(width+0.01) for x in xlocations]
positions_group2 = xlocations

plt.boxplot(data_group1, 
            sym=symbol,
            labels=['']*len(labels_list),
            positions=positions_group1, 
            widths=width, 
#           notch=False,  
#           vert=True, 
#           whis=1.5,
#           bootstrap=None, 
#           usermedians=None, 
#           conf_intervals=None,
#           patch_artist=False,
            )

plt.boxplot(data_group2, 
            labels=labels_list,
            sym=symbol,
            positions=positions_group2, 
            widths=width, 
#           notch=False,  
#           vert=True, 
#           whis=1.5,
#           bootstrap=None, 
#           usermedians=None, 
#           conf_intervals=None,
#           patch_artist=False,
            )

plt.savefig('boxplot_grouped.png')  
plt.savefig('boxplot_grouped.pdf')    # when publishing, use high quality PDFs
#plt.show()                   # uncomment to show the plot.
```

Comment: What I prefer in the other solutions is that the axis label is centered under the group.

Comment: I agree, it's sad there's no simple and beautiful plot from matplotlib by default. That's what I'm trying to push forward with this version. Recommendation or community edits to fix (and test Py2/3) axis label centering welcome.

Comment: How would you add an additional group? For example, if we had another label `c` where `data_group3 = [data4, data5]`?

Comment: @pookie so true, I am also looking how to solve the puzzle. Things not in order if we just add another group in the script

Comment: @Azam @pookie - adjust the offsets. `x-(width+0.01)` is just moving the position of `x` (for group1) to the left.. so (In theory) increase how much you move group1 left e.g. `group1=x-(width*2+0.01); group2=x-(width*1+0.01); group3=xlocations`. [not-tested]

Answer (score 0):

I used the [code given by Kuzeko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63243881/18236202) and it worked well, but I found that the boxes in each group were being drawn in the reverse order. I changed `...x-_off...` to `...x+_off...` in the following line (just above the last for loop) which fixes it for me:

```
group_positions.append([x+_off*(width+0.01) for x in xlocations])
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
A boxplot above was modified to obtain group boxplots with 3 data types.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np



 ord = [[16.9423,
               4.0410,
               19.1185],
           [18.5134,
               17.8048,
               19.2669],
           [18.7286,
               18.0576,
               19.1717],
           [18.8998,
               18.8469,
               19.0005],
           [18.8126,
               18.7870,
               18.8393],
           [18.7770,
               18.7511,
               18.8022],
           [18.7409,
               18.7075,
               18.7747],
           [18.6866,
               18.6624,
               18.7093
               ],
           [18.6748],
           [18.9069,
                18.6752,
                19.0769],
           [19.0012,
                18.9783,
                19.0202
                ],
           [18.9448,
               18.9134,
               18.9813],
           [19.1242,
               18.8256,
               19.3185],
           [19.2118,
               19.1661,
               19.2580],
           [19.2505,
               19.1231,
               19.3526]]
    
    seq = [[17.8092,
              4.0410,
              19.6653],
           [18.7266,
              18.2556,
              19.3739],
           [18.6051,
              18.0589,
              19.0557],
           [18.6467,
              18.5629,
              18.7566],
           [18.5307,
              18.4999,
              18.5684],
           [18.4732,
              18.4484,
              18.4985],
           [18.5234,
              18.5027,
              18.4797,
              18.4573],
           [18.3987,
              18.3636,
              18.4544],
           [18.3593],
           [18.7234,
               18.7092,
               18.7598],
           [18.7438,
               18.7224,
               18.7677],
           [18.7304,
               18.7111,
               18.6880,
               18.6913,
               18.6678],
           [18.8926,
               18.5902,
               19.2003],
           [19.1059,
               19.0835,
               19.0601,
               19.0373,
               19.0147],
           [19.1925,
               19.0177,
               19.2588]]
    
    apd=[[17.0331,
            4.0410,
            18.5670],
         [17.6124,
            17.1975,
            18.0755],
         [17.3956,
            17.1572,
            17.9140],
         [17.8295,
            17.6514,
            18.1466],
         [18.0665,
            17.9144,
            18.2157],
         [18.1518,
            18.0382,
            18.2722],
         [18.1975,
            18.0956,
            18.2987],
         [18.2219,
            18.1293,
            18.3062],
         [18.2870,
            18.2215,
            18.3513],
         [18.3047,
             18.2363,
             18.3950],
         [18.3580,
             18.2923,
             18.4205],
         [18.3830,
             18.3250,
             18.4381],
         [18.4135,
             18.3645,
             18.4753],
         [18.4580,
             18.4095,
             18.5170],
         [18.4900,
             18.4430,
             18.5435]
         ]
    ticks = [120,
             240,
             360,
             516,
             662,
             740,
             874,
             1022,
             1081,
             1201,
             1320,
             1451,
             1562,
             1680,
             1863]
    
    def set_box_color(bp, color):
        plt.setp(bp['boxes'], color=color)
        plt.setp(bp['whiskers'], color=color)
        plt.setp(bp['caps'], color=color)
        plt.setp(bp['medians'], color=color)
    
    plt.figure()
    
    bpl = plt.boxplot(ord, positions=np.array(range(len(ord)))*3.0-0.3, sym='', widths=0.6)
    bpr = plt.boxplot(seq, positions=np.array(range(len(seq)))*3.0+0.3, sym='', widths=0.6)
    bpg = plt.boxplot(apd, positions=np.array(range(len(apd)))*3.0+0.9, sym='', widths=0.6)
    set_box_color(bpl, '#D7191C') # colors are from http://colorbrewer2.org/
    set_box_color(bpr, '#2C7BB6')
    set_box_color(bpg, '#99d8c9')
    # draw temporary red and blue lines and use them to create a legend
    plt.plot([], c='#D7191C', label='ORD')
    plt.plot([], c='#2C7BB6', label='SEQ')
    plt.plot([], c='#99d8c9', label='APD')
    plt.legend()
    
    plt.xticks(range(0, len(ticks) * 3, 3), ticks)
    plt.xlim(-2, len(ticks)*3)
    plt.ylim(0, 20)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
    plt.savefig('boxcompare.png')
```

Comment: What does this code do? How is it different or any improvement over the 8 previous answers?

Comment: This code provides the solution to add group boxplots with 3 data types whereas the above code was only for two types of data. Further, the labelling did not occur correctly in one of the above codes where a grouped box plot with 3 data types was presented.