# Group Boxplots with multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I have tried to create a scatter with grouped boxplots as the ones on the following links:

[matplotlib: Group boxplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16592222/matplotlib-group-boxplots)

https://cmdlinetips.com/2019/03/how-to-make-grouped-boxplots-in-python-with-seaborn/

[how to make a grouped boxplot graph in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20365122/how-to-make-a-grouped-boxplot-graph-in-matplotlib?noredirect=1&lq=1)

However, the data I want to use comes in a format as:

[5y_spreads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VetUC.png)

[7y_spreads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uRdz.png)

[10y_spreads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBf0D.png)

(each of the images above comes from a different worksheet in the same workbook)

I need to work the data in Python to make it ready for *seaborn* and that is what is difficult for me.
It is not structured as in the examples from the links. I understand this requires mastering *dataframes* (something I am still learning).

I also need to show the latest value to see where the bonds are trading now, compared to the range.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It will be easier to help you if you use a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Besides, your question is too broad. You will need to be more specific. Are you looking for a boxplot grouped by stock where each boxplot represents the spreads? Or are you looking for a boxplot grouped by spread where each boxplot represents a stock?

Comment: Thank you Chris. I was looking to group box plots by Company, so that each boxplot would represent the variation for the spread of that company in a specific maturity. Y axis is the Spread, X axis is each company and each company will have 3 boxplots grouped.