# Different colours for different boxes for box plot generated by matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, boxplot

I am using matplotlib in Python to generate box plot. I want to make different boxes in different colours. Is there a way to do that?

[Figure](http://matplotlib.org/_images/boxplot_demo_00_00.png)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16592222/matplotlib-group-boxplots

Comment: The matplotlib gallery has an example: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/boxplot_demo2.html