# Hierarchial plotting of pandas dataframe showing boxplot visualization

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

I have a multivariate dataset that looks like this:
[image]

My goal is to generate a boxplot to visualize the distribution of values in Treat1, Treat2 , Treat3 and Treat4.

I can get to a barchart to get exactly what I want based on 
[How to add group labels for bar charts in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184484/how-to-add-group-labels-for-bar-charts-in-matplotlib)
[image]

However my requirement is for  box plot to look at the distribution between mean and outliers for each Treat group.
I am pasting the code again that generates the bar graph that is based on the  stackoverflow code https://stackoverflow.com/users/2846871/varicus

```
df = df2.groupby(['Group','Category','Day ']).sum()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
df.plot(kind='bar',stacked=False,ax=fig.gca())
labels = ['' for item in ax.get_xticklabels()]
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax.set_xlabel('')
label_group_bar_table(ax, df)
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=.1*df.index.nlevels)
plt.show()
```

What would be the best way to generate a Boxplot instead of each bar.

Comment: Did you see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16592222/matplotlib-group-boxplots)?

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you are looking for.

```
# I create a dataframe similar to yours for others to give other solutions.

group = [1,1,1,1,2,2,4,4, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1]
cateogry = [0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,0,0,1,1,0,0,2,2,2]
Treat1 = np.random.randint(0, 100, size= len(group))
Treat2 = np.random.randint(0, 100, size= len(group))
Treat3 = np.random.randint(0, 100, size= len(group))
Treat4 = np.random.randint(0, 100, size= len(group))
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Group': group, "Category": cateogry, "Treat1": Treat1,"Treat2": Treat2,"Treat3": Treat3,"Treat4": Treat4, })

f = df.boxplot(by = ['Group','Category'],figsize = (12,8))
```

will result in 
[image]

Comment: This graph doesnt take into account column A which is'day side by side . so that I can compare how Group values were on Day 0 compared to day 20

Answer (score 0):

I added part of the code which does the job however I wanted that each category had it's own face color. I can't seem to distinguish between categories through graph.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (20,8))


#Note showfliers=False is more readable, but requires a recent version iirc
bp = df_Dummy.boxplot(by = ['Group','Category','Day '],ax=ax, 
sym='',rot=90,return_type='dict',patch_artist=False)


[[item.set_linewidth(2) for item in bp[key]['boxes']] for key in bp.keys()]


[[item.set_linewidth(2) for item in bp[key]['fliers']] for key in bp.keys()]
[[item.set_linewidth(2) for item in bp[key]['medians']] for key in bp.keys()]
[[item.set_linewidth(2) for item in bp[key]['means']] for key in bp.keys()]
[[item.set_linewidth(2) for item in bp[key]['whiskers']] for key in bp.keys()]
[[item.set_linewidth(2) for item in bp[key]['caps']] for key in bp.keys()]
colors = ['pink', 'lightblue', 'lightgreen','yellow']
[[item.set_color in zip(colors) for item in bp[key]['boxes']] for key in bp.keys()]
# seems to have no effect
[[item.set_color('b') for item in bp[key]['fliers']] for key in bp.keys()]
[[item.set_color('m') for item in bp[key]['medians']] for key in bp.keys()]
[[item.set_markerfacecolor('k') for item in bp[key]['means']] for key in bp.keys()]
[[item.set_color('c') for item in bp[key]['whiskers']] for key in bp.keys()]
[[item.set_color('y') for item in bp[key]['caps']] for key in bp.keys()]

ax.margins(y=0.05)
```

[image]