# 2 box per each category from 2 dataframe python boxplot

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

I have 2 data frame like this:
[image]

I want to create a box plot like this for them based on their indexes:
[image]

How can I do that? I just can make a separate box plot for each data frame.

I couldnt draw this plot with other topics

Comment: Possible duplicate of [matplotlib: Group boxplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16592222/matplotlib-group-boxplots)

Comment: @KristianK. help me, I couldnt apply that on my problem

Comment: You copied the image from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16592222/matplotlib-group-boxplots). Did you actually try any of the 6 answers given over there? What is the problem?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have data frame but in that post is just a list of data

Comment: Each column of a dataframe is a 1D array and a 1D array can be seen as list. But also the complete dataframe is a 2D array (which you get as array via `df.values`), so that is good enough as input for a boxplot.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest What are Positions in a dataframe? Positions is defined [1,2] in that topic

Comment: You could use `np.arange(len(df.columns))-0.5` and `np.arange(len(df.columns))+0.5`  respectively.