# make boxplot with columns from 2 dataframes [python seaborn]

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I want to make a boxplot like this:

[image]

My data looks like this. It's separated into a control and an intervention dataframe.

```
control_df
   # of Days
0         10
1         12
2         30
```

```
intervention_df
   # of Days
0          2
1          1
2          2
```

Unfortunately, I'm not able to easily put it into sns.boxplot. Any advice on how to format it to graph appreciated.

MVE below:

```python
import pandas as pd

# This is how my actual data is coming in
data_control = {'# of Days':[10,12,30]}
data_intervention = {'# of Days':[2,1,2]}

control_df = pd.DataFrame(data_control)
intervention_df = pd.DataFrame(data_intervention)

# This is me manually making it better for a boxplot
boxplot_data = {'Type':['control','control','control','intervention','intervention','intervention'],
                '# of Days':[10,12,30,2,1,2]}

import seaborn as sns

sns.boxplot(x='Type',y='# of Days',data=boxplot_data)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [matplotlib: Group boxplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16592222/matplotlib-group-boxplots)

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not able to understand by how that q is phrased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `pd.concat` with `keys` parameter and `droplevel`:

```
sns.boxplot(data=pd.concat([control_df, intervention_df], 
                           axis=1, 
                           keys=['Control', 'Intervention']).droplevel(1, axis=1))
```

Output:

[image]