# How to make a nested / grouped boxplot using seaborn of a 3D array

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm trying to make a nested boxplot like in this SO[-answer for matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16592222/matplotlib-group-boxplots), but I have trouble figuring out how to create my dataframe.

Goal of this is to make some kind of sensitivity analysis of a PCA model representing object positions (in 3D); where I can see how well a PCA model is able to represent an arch-like distribution, based on the number of PCA components I'm using.

So I have an array of shape (n_pca_components, n_samples, n_objects) containing the distances of the objects to their 'ideal' position on an arch. What I am able to boxplot is this (example showing random data):
[image: non-nested-boxplot]
This is - I assume - an aggregated boxplot (statistics gathered over the first two axes of my array); I want to create a boxplot with the same x- and y-axes, but for each 'obj_..' I want a boxplot for each value along the first axis of my data (`n_pca_components)`, i.e. something like this (where days correspond to 'obj_i's, 'total_bill' to my stored distances and 'smoker' to each entry along the first axis of my array.

[image: nested-boxplot]

I read around but got lost in the concepts of panda's multi-indexing, groupby, (un)stack, reset_index, ... All examples I see have a different data structure and I think that's where the problem lies, I haven't yet made the mental 'click' and am thinking in wrong data structures.

What I have so far is this (using random/example data):

```
n_pca_components = 5  # Let's say I want to make this analysis for using 3, 6, 9, 12, 15 PCA components
n_objects = 14   # 14 objects per sample
n_samples = 100  # 100 samples

# Create random data
mses = np.random.rand(n_pca_components, n_samples, n_objects)   # Simulated errors

# Create column names
n_comps = [f'{(i+1) * 3}' for i in range(n_pca_components)]
object_ids = [f'obj_{i}' for i in range(n_objects)]
samples = [f'sample_{i}' for i in range(n_samples)]

# Create panda dataframe
mses_pd = mses.reshape(-1, 14)
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([n_comps, samples], names=['n_comps', 'samples'])

mses_frame = pd.DataFrame(data=mses_pd, index=midx, columns=object_ids)

# Make a nested boxplot with `object_ids` on the 'large' X-axis and `n_comps` on each 'nested' X-axis; and the box-statistics about the mses stored in `mses_frame` on the y-axis.

# Things I tried (yes, I'm a complete pandas-newbie). I've been reading a lot of SO-posts and documentation but cannot seem to figure out how to do what I want.
sns.boxplot(data=mses_frame, hue='n_comps')  # ValueError: Cannot use `hue` without `x` and `y`
sns.boxplot(data=mses_frame, hue='n_comps', x='object_ids') # ValueError: Could not interpret input 'object_ids'
sns.boxplot(data=mses_frame, hue='n_comps', x=object_ids) # ValueError: Could not interpret input 'n_comps'
sns.boxplot(data=mses_frame, hue=n_comps, x=object_ids) # ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

[image]

While I think seaborn can handle wide data, I personally find it easier to work with ["tidy data"](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) (or long data). To convert your dataframe from the "wide" to "long" you can use [`DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and make sure to preserve your input.

So

```py
>>> mses_frame.melt(ignore_index=False)

                  variable     value
n_comps samples
3       sample_0     obj_0  0.424960
        sample_1     obj_0  0.758884
        sample_2     obj_0  0.408663
        sample_3     obj_0  0.440811
        sample_4     obj_0  0.112798
...                    ...       ...
15      sample_95   obj_13  0.172044
        sample_96   obj_13  0.381045
        sample_97   obj_13  0.364024
        sample_98   obj_13  0.737742
        sample_99   obj_13  0.762252

[7000 rows x 2 columns]
```

Again, seaborn probably can work with this somehow (maybe someone else can comment on this) but I find it easier to reset the index so your multi indices become columns

```py
>>> mses_frame.melt(ignore_index=False).reset_index()

     n_comps    samples variable     value
0          3   sample_0    obj_0  0.424960
1          3   sample_1    obj_0  0.758884
2          3   sample_2    obj_0  0.408663
3          3   sample_3    obj_0  0.440811
4          3   sample_4    obj_0  0.112798
...      ...        ...      ...       ...
6995      15  sample_95   obj_13  0.172044
6996      15  sample_96   obj_13  0.381045
6997      15  sample_97   obj_13  0.364024
6998      15  sample_98   obj_13  0.737742
6999      15  sample_99   obj_13  0.762252

[7000 rows x 4 columns]
```

Now you can decide what you want to plot, I think you are saying you want

```py
sns.boxplot(x="variable", y="value", hue="n_comps", 
            data=mses_frame.melt(ignore_index=False).reset_index())
```

Let me know if I've misunderstood something

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! Thanks a bunch!