# Make boxplots side by side instead of overlap

Tags: python, boxplot

I want to make boxplots using data from two files. I can use code below for one of them:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("file1", sep=r'\s+', header=0)
df1.boxplot(['VAL'], by=['LABEL'])
```

I tried to use code below for combining two dataset on one plot, but instead of side by side, the two sets of plots are overlapped.

```
a1=df1[['VAL','LABEL']]
ax = a1.boxplot(by='LABEL', return_type='axes')
a2=df2[['VAL','LABEL']]
a2.boxplot(by='LABEL', ax=ax)
```

[image]

A sample of FILE1 is attached, FILE2 has same structure except the numbers are different.

```
LABEL VAL
A     0.1
A     0.5
A     0.3
B     0.2
B     0.4
B     -0.5
B     0.2
B     0.1
C     -0.2
C     0.3
C     0.1
C     0.2
D     0.5
D     0.1
```

Btw, I know seaborn can do this, but I can not use "seaborn". Thank you for help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [matplotlib: Group boxplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16592222/matplotlib-group-boxplots)

Comment: @frippe, thank you for your answer. It is very similar to m question. But the input data format is different, and I don't know how to change the code to meet my input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the `position` parameter to move the different dfs to the left or right. I have added a color as well, so you can see the difference. I have used the same code you have and added the additions to change position and color. Data is random. Hope this is what you are looking for...

```
a1=df1[['VAL','LABEL']]
ax = a1.boxplot(by='LABEL', positions=np.array(range(df1.LABEL.nunique()))*2.0-0.5, boxprops=dict(color='blue'),return_type='axes')
a2=df2[['VAL','LABEL']]
a2.boxplot(by='LABEL', positions=np.array(range(df2.LABEL.nunique()))*2.0+0.5, boxprops=dict(color='red'),ax=ax)

plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 2*(df1.LABEL.nunique()), 2), labels=df1.LABEL.unique())
```

**Output plot**

[image]

**Using Seaborn**

As I was completing adding labels, just realized that, if you are ok using seaborn (instead of matplotlib), you can do this much more easily. Added the code for that as well here...

```
df= pd.concat([df1,df2],keys=["df1", "df2"]).reset_index()
sns.boxplot(data=df, x="LABEL", y="VAL", hue="level_0")
plt.legend([],[], frameon=False)
```

**Output Plot**
[image]

Comment: thank you. Yes, this works well. But how to remove one set of the X-label (A,B,C,D) so the two dataset can share the label (because the original label is very long,like 20230101-0101) . Also I got  "UserWarning: When passing multiple axes, sharex and sharey are ignored. These settings must be specified when creating axes". ax = boxplot(" Should I just ignore this warning or there is a way to fix that?

Comment: Hi - I have added the line to remove add the ticks in correct position. Also, realized it is much easier to do this with seaborn... see if this helps. For I am not sure of sharex as it is not used in this code. Can't advise as there is no such error. Perhaps add another question showcasing the issue

Comment: your help is much appreciated.