# Multiple boxplots & groups with Matplotlib axes.bxp

Tags: matplotlib, boxplot

I am making an enhanced version of this:

[image]

Using the graphic as a reference, my `1` and `2` come from the different values in `my_data_col` below.  My grouping columns (`Weeks` in the graphic) are `group_1` and `group_2`- `group_2` is a subgroup of `group_1`.

I can't figure out how to do the grouping.

I'm using [matplotlib.axes.axesx.bxp](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bxp.html) because the data is large, I do the calculations on the database side and export the data.

The closest answer I've found is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63243881/3225420) but it's not quite there.

Sample `DataFrame` of my `SQL` results:

| my_data_col | group_1 | group_2 | med | q1 | q3 | whislo | whishi |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dist_to_datum | high | center | 145.9 | 145.8 | 146.1 | 145.3 | 146.6 |
| dist_to_datum | high | left | 100.2 | 88.3 | 110.8 | 54.6 | 144.6 |
| dist_to_datum | high | right | 156.1 | 155.1 | 159.0 | 149.2 | 164.9 |
| dist_to_datum | low | center | 56.3 | 52.3 | 64.0 | 34.7 | 81.6 |
| dist_to_datum | low | left | 38.6 | 36.7 | 38.7 | 33.7 | 41.7 |
| dist_to_datum | low | right | 64.1 | 62.7 | 66.6 | 56.9 | 72.4 |
| dist_to_apex | high | center | 161.1 | 158.8 | 162.7 | 153.0 | 168.5 |
| dist_to_apex | high | left | 164.1 | 162.3 | 164.2 | 159.5 | 167.0 |
| dist_to_apex | high | right | 157.4 | 157.1 | 159.1 | 154.1 | 162.1 |
| dist_to_apex | low | center | 71.5 | 70.0 | 77.1 | 59.4 | 87.7 |
| dist_to_apex | low | left | 70.1 | 68.7 | 70.6 | 65.9 | 73.4 |
| dist_to_apex | low | right | 69.5 | 69.1 | 69.7 | 68.2 | 70.6 |

### Commentary on possible duplicates

I am aware of the axes.bxp answers on SO, I've read them and wrote the SQL query the way I did because of them.

There are no answers on SO to my knowledge that address how to group with multiple columns using axes.bxp, which is challenging and thus the question.