# Seaborn boxplot color outliers by hue variable using seaborn =< 0.12.2

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I would like to color my boxplot-outliers in my Seaborn Boxplot when using a hue variables. Something along the line of this, from [seaborn boxplot examples](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html#), but I am stuck on seaborn ver. 0.12.2

[image: sns.boxplot(data=titanic, x="class", y="age", hue="alive", fill=False, gap=.1)]

As I'm stuck here I get this. What should I change? Any way it's possible in this seaborn version?  It's unfortunately currently not an option for me to update my working environment. Thanks.

[image]

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Sample data
data = sns.load_dataset('tips')

# Boxplot with outliers colored by hue variable ('sex' in this 
sns.boxplot(data=data, x='day', y='total_bill', hue='sex')

plt.show()
```

Comment: `fill=False`, if you have version 0.13.0+. If not, more work is needed. Do you want the boxes to be filled still?

Comment: The easiest would be to directly use matplotlib. See e.g. [How to create grouped boxplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16592222/how-to-create-grouped-boxplots).